# How many css files can you cache into one file in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey! I was watching the RailsCasts on Formtastic and he cached all of the files into one file this way:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', 'formtastic', 'formtastic_changes', :cache => "base" %>
```

This made it so all of the css files would be read into one big file which is base.css now but are still split up in development i believe.

How far can this go, can you have any amount of style sheets and put them in one file this way during production mode? Is this practice OK?

Comment: Just wondering if my answer worked for you.

Comment: Yep, sure did, just got busy working on the answer you gave me in my last question, thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use this to concatenate any amount of files and it is good for use in production when you want to reduce requests to the server. This has been enhanced in Rails 3.1 with the introduction of the asset pipeline and new features related to it.

Also, this is a good practice in production because you generally want to keep things as small as possible for speed and performance and this includes asset requests to the server. You might want to look into minification for production as well, this strips any whitespace as well as comments and would help you serve up smaller files.

Comment: Hey Devin, if i make many css files, is there a way to declare all of them without writing each and every single sheet? Does this code work? <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all, :cache => true %>